# In my React application, how can I add a newline after each item in this map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I have this redux selector I've been working on in my React application.  I've made good progress but I've hit a wall with this last issue i'm working on and I feel like it shouldn't be that difficult to solve but I'm struggling.

What I'm trying to achieve is after each item has been mapped, the next item must go to a new line.

```
export const vLineRejectionSelector = createSelector(
  selectedVIdSelector,
  linesSelector,
  (id, lines) =>
    lines
      .filter(line => line.id === id)
      .map(
        (rejectString, index) =>
          `Line: ${index + 1} ${rejectString.rejectReason}`
      )
);
```

The only relevant code to look at in this is the map function.  I want each item to go to a new line as its being mapped.

The output should look something like:

```
Line 1: Reject Reason One
Line 2: Reject Reason Two
```

Instead the output looks like:

```
Line1: Reject ReasonOneLine2: Reject Reason Two
```

This is being rendered in JSX as well

The value of this is passed around as a prop and gets rendered in the JSX like:

```
        <Typography variant="body2">
          {rejectReason}
          {reasons && reasons.join(', ')}
        </Typography>
```

Its value is {rejectReason}.

Comment: You’re outputting HTML right? I would assume you need a break element to insert new lines `<br>`

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against composing JSX in your selector and rather just return the lines as an array as you are doing currently, but then map it to either a list or a simple `<br />` joined list in the `render()` function. This keeps your selector more easily testable and also doesn't mix state selection concerns with presentational concerns.

E.g:
**in your container**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    rejectReason: vLineRejectionSelector(state)
  }
}

const SomeComponentContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SomeComponent)

export default SomeComponentContainer
```

and then in your `SomeComponent`s render function:

```
<Typography variant="body2">
   {this.props.rejectReason.map((rejectReason) => <>Line: {index + 1} {rejectReason}<br /></>)}
</Typography>
```

Comment: Hmm, that <br/> inside the string interpolation isnt working as intended

Comment: @ghostagent151 Sorry, haven't worked with React for a while. Updated the answer to wrap it in fragments.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `<br />` tag at the end of each line.

Like `Line: ${index + 1} ${rejectString.rejectReason}<br />`

Comment: I've updated the description for the question so its a little clearer.  That wont work since its value is passed around as a prop.  Im starting to think I need to restructure the component its getting rendered on.

Comment: Yes, that is a great idea. Get the reasons as array from the selector then loop that array to render `<Typography />` component for each reason. This will solve your problem for sure.